# Reuse function as pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators, fixtures

I have a function in my code that is being used by fastapi to provide a db session to the endpoints:

```
def get_db() -> Generator[Session, None, None]:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I want to use the same function as a pytest fixture. If I do something like the following, the fixture is not being recognized:

```
pytest.fixture(get_db, name="db", scope="session")

def test_item_create(db: Session) -> None:
    ...
```

`test_item_create` throws an error about `db` not being a fixture: `fixture 'db' not found`.

So I can rewrite `get_db` in my `conftest.py` and wrap it with `pytest.fixture` and get things working, but I was wondering if there's a better way of reusing existing functions as fixtures. If I have more helper functions like `get_db`, it'd be nice not to have rewrite them for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `pytest` cannot find the fixture as things are written in your example. Maybe you are trying to get to something like this?

```py
db = pytest.fixture(get_db, name="db", scope="session")

def test_item_create(db: Session) -> None:
    ...
```